# Asking manager for more work politely

Tags: software-industry, communication, task-management

I joined in an IT company 3 years back but around 2 weeks back i got transferred to a new location under new manager.I have not yet assigned with any work.How do i ask politely to my manager to assign some work to me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. "Hi, Manager. Now that I've spent a couple of weeks getting acquainted with the people and procedures here, I'd really like to start contributing. Is there anything you'd like me to start with? Or should I check around the department and see who needs an extra pair of eyes/hands for something?"

Basically, whatever you say that is polite and shows that you want to contribute is good. Don't over-think it.